# Listbox is not getting a vertical scrollbar

Tags: c#, xaml

The main issue people seem to have with the vertical scrollbar not appearing is because they use a stackpanel. I went through my complete visual tree and my listbox is not in a stackpanel anywhere.

Here is the XAML that I use:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ReportToListItem x:Key="reportToListItem" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Background="PaleGoldenrod" x:Name="Controller_Domain_Reports_OpenReports">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Converter={StaticResource reportToListItem}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" Height="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <ListBox Background="Magenta" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Controller_Domain_Reports_ClosedReports">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Converter={StaticResource reportToListItem}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Neither listbox gets a scrollbar if it extends beyond the height of the window for me. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Do you have any size-constrains on any component, even the base window? I'm not sure, but think that could be a problem. Try setting width/height for the Grid and see what happens.

Comment: Do'h.. The shellview had a nice copy pasted list of rowdefinitions all set to auto. Changed the one that contains this view to * and now it works as expected. Thanks for the help, could you post it as an answer to I can close this off? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just putting this up to close this off properly:

Do'h.. The shellview had a nice copy pasted list of rowdefinitions all set to auto. Changed the one that contains this view to * and now it works as expected.